# how to migrate my java script button to lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, custom-button

I used configuration converter to migrate JS button to lightning enabled. but it's not working as expected. Pleas help me on this. see my javascript code below.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")} 


var acc = new sforce.SObject("Account"); 
acc.id = "{!Account.Id}"; 

acc.RPS_Account_Checkbox__c = true; 
sforce.connection.update([acc]); 

window.location.reload();
```

> Note: when click on this button it will call outbound message in
>   workflow rule.

Comment: What do you mean it is not working as expected? What exactly are you trying to run?

Comment: @kurunve, i can able to see button but the checkbox is not getting updated when  click on the button. so the script functionality is not working when using converter.  i would like to see the code of component,helper,controller to make it work